# Update Fuerte to 1.8.10 breaks rospkg

Tags: rosdep, update, ros-fuerte, rospkg, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yesterday, I used apt-get to update my Fuerte to 1.8.10, and then I could no longer run a roscore.  I was getting an error about the author tag in the file `/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros_comm/stack.xml`. I did some searching and found [this](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3986) bug which said that it was a problem with rospkg that had been fixed in version `1.0.6`.

The problem was fixed by running

```
sudo easy_install -U rospkg
```

My question is the following: Using ROS tools, how could I have automatically made this upgrade? Should `rosdep` be used to handle upgrades to components that are not installed via OS repositories?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37397/update-fuerte-to-1.8.10-breaks-rospkg/) by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9031 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, rospkg should not be installed using easy_install or pip anymore. It is now provided by the Debian package python-rospkg which is probably already installed on your system since it is a dependency of ros. Just get rid of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg and the corresponding egg file if present.

**Edit**: I've investigated the issue a little more and it turns out that rospkg is installed when rosdep is installed according to the install instructions using easy_install or pip in `/usr/local`. So what I guess happened was that people installed ROS correctly in the first place, then came the breaking ROS update without any message that it's now necessary to also update rosdep/rospkg. So the correct solution, at least for now, is probably to update rospkg by hand using pip or easy_install. I hope this will be fixed soon.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-27**:
I am having a similar problem. That fix did not work for me (on Oneiric). Although I have `python-rospkg` installed, it seems to be missing from $PATH.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-27**:
The `easy_install` command (above) *did* work. Strangely, `pip install` did not. Something really screwy is going on here.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-27**:
Interesting. For me getting rid of the easy_installed thing worked. Just out of curiosity, what was the python backtrace you were getting?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-27**:
@joq with pip and easy_install I've had some issues with them creating a "build" directory in the current directory and if that already exists, it installs from there instead of the new version.  Even if you use the -U option, and it downloads the new tarball.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-06-27**:
Indeed, removing all references to the rospkg egg files, and relying on the already-installed version in python-rospkg also worked.

**Comment by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on 2012-06-28**:
Could someone explain how to do this specifically?  I've moved the egg files (never had a plain rospkg folder in the path listed above), fully uninstalled ros-fuerte (using apt-get, so maybe that won't reach everything), did a clean install, and roscore still errors out.

**Comment by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on 2012-06-28**:
I can post a full backtrace if requested, but rosversion fails to load with the final error of "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: rospkg==1.0.4"

**Comment by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on 2012-06-28**:
Sorry for the repeated posts.  The easy_install solution seems to have worked. Is there a reason to prefer one solution over another?  Thanks for the help

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-28**:
On a freshly installed Ubuntu, the package that provides rospkg is python-rospkg, no easy_install is necessary. It seems like there has also been the package ros-fuerte-rospkg. I would get rid of the easy-installed version and ros-fuerte-rospkg and use python-rospkg.

**Comment by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on 2012-06-28**:
Sorry to be a newbie, but how do I get rid of the easy_install version? easy_inst's help says nothing about uninstalling.  And mine was a fresh reinstallation of ROS, but not Ubuntu.  After this, dpkg no longer reports ros-fuerte-rospkg, though it still did not work until I tried the easy_inst way

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-28**:
easy_install puts the rospkg into /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg or something similar (maybe python 2.6, maybe site-packages depending on your ubuntu version). Delete that directory and the rospkg egg file. In the backtrace you see where the erroneous python files are.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-29**:
In addition, on my Fuerte/Oneiric system I had to `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/rosversion`, which had been left lying around by something.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-03-14**:
A good description of how to cleanup the installs: http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153